# Reinstall a Shimano nexus 7 wheel after puncture?

Tags: shimano, maintenance, gears, hybrid-bike, nexus

I took my back wheel off to fix the tube. When trying to put back together the "gear cassette" I was struggling, it just wouldn’t fit.

I eventually checked a youtube video that explains how the yellow dots should be aligned. By doing that it worked however the length of the gear wire is now messed up and when putting the gear on 4 the yellow dots DO NOT ALIGN. They did before I dismantled the gear cassette.

I think the gears work but it doesn’t seem right. I cannot test the bike because the tube is leaking again and I need to fix it again, nightmare! I worry I have messed up the gear cable and I wouldn’t know how to put it back how it was before. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. I suggest taking the [tour] because sthis site works quite specifically. I do not understand which yellow dots you mean or which cable you have in mind. Do you have a picture? What cassette and derailer brand do you have? What bike is it?

Comment: I suggest you [edit] in a couple of photographs of the state it is in now, as well as removing any reference to a _cassette_ in the question. You have an internal hub gear, which does not use a cassette. It's also unclear why the thing is disassembled, to remove the wheel you would normally simply detach the cable without disassembling the hub or altering the length of the cable. So adding photos will help a lot

Comment: @Swifty Shimano's jargon is a bit daft - the bracket that holds the single cog on, and also supports the incoming gear cable is called a "cassette joint"

Comment: To patch a hole you do not need to take out the wheel and so not unhook the gear cable. There are videos online and at least one question on this site.

Comment: thank you all for your comments and apologies for the incorrect jargon, I am not an expert.  I needed to take the tire off because the tire was super tight and I needed to apply pressure when taking it off. I couldn't have done it if was on, anyway I thank you all for your help and I will try and post pictures. thank you

Answer (score 3):

The yellow dots should be lined up when in a specific gear, which is gear 4 for a 7 speed nexus, (gear 6 for an 11 speed alfine)

Generally speaking, to change tube on an IGH wheel you need to get the wheel off the bike.

- Release rim brakes to make room for tyre to pass through
- Undo wheel nuts with 15mm spanner - your bike won't have a quick release.
- Unclip the control cable from the rotary part, and pull the chromed cap off the retainer.

Then the wheel should come free (actual method depends if you have a tensioner, or if the bike had dropouts or trackends, etc)   and you can do the tube swap or patch the hole.

To reinstall the wheel, its roughly the reverse.   You should not need to adjust the cable in any way - the clamped on stop on the inner cable won't have moved.

If you've somehow undone the "cassette joint" and parts are coming off the side of the hub, then something has gone quite wrong.  Please post a clear well-lit photo of the right side of your hub, and perhaps the right side of your bike too.